# React Navigation 5 pass params to screen inside nested navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab, react-navigation-v5

We are migrating an app in React Navigation 4 to React Navigation 5.
The project has a BottomTabNavigator which has for one of its routes a nested TopTabNavigator with three tabs. One of the tabs in the BottomTabNavigator when pressed navigates to a Sorting Screen where you select the sort parameter to sort by and then navigates to the "Pending" route adding the selected sort parameter, which should reach one of the three List screens inside the TopTabNavigator.
Currently I'm recieving inside those screens the route.params as null which I asume is cause theres another navigator in the middle (topTabNavigator).

BottomTabNavigator

```
    <BottomTabsNavigator.Navigator
      tabBar={props => <CustomTabBar {...props} />}
      initialRouteName="Pending"
    >
      <BottomTabsNavigator.Screen name="Pending" component={createTopTabsNavigator} />
      <BottomTabsNavigator.Screen name="Sort" component={SortScreen} />
      <BottomTabsNavigator.Screen name="Tab 3" component={Fragment} />
      <BottomTabsNavigator.Screen name="Tab 4" component={Fragment} /> 
      <BottomTabsNavigator.Screen name="Tab 5" component={Fragment} />
      <BottomTabsNavigator.Screen name="Filter" component={Fragment} />
    </BottomTabsNavigator.Navigator>
```

SortScreen tab:

```
    handleOnPress(item: { text: string; value: string; }): void {
        const {navigation} = this.props;

        const param = {orderBy: item.value};
        navigation.navigate('Pending', param);
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={orderOptions}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        <ListItem style={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }} onPress={() => this.handleOnPress(item)}>
                            <Body>
                                <Text>{item.text}</Text>
                            </Body>
                        </ListItem>
                    )}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.text}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
```

createTopTabsNavigator:

```
    <TopTabsNavigator.Navigator>
      <TopTabsNavigator.Screen name="List1" component={Screen1} />
      <TopTabsNavigator.Screen name="List2" component={Screen2} />
      <TopTabsNavigator.Screen name="List3" component={Screen3} />
    </TopTabsNavigator.Navigator>
```

A hand with this issue is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```js
navigation.navigate('Root', {
  screen: 'Settings',
  params: { user: 'jane' },
});
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/nesting-navigators.html#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator

Comment: Awesome, now I need to get which screen was active from the nested navigator when the tab was clicked, any ideas? cause each of the three screens have a list that should be able to be sorted